# Algebra/Negative Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does $\frac{a^{-1}-b^{-1}}{a^{-1/2}-b^{-1/2}}=\frac{\sqrt{a}}a+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{b}$?

I understand it equals $\frac{a^{1/2}-b^{1/2}}{a-b}$ but I can't figure out the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to see it is to factor the numerator.

$$\frac{a^{-1}-b^{-1}}{a^{-1/2}-b^{-1/2}}=\frac{(a^{-1/2}-b^{-1/2})(a^{-1/2}+b^{-1/2})}{a^{-1/2}-b^{-1/2}}=a^{-1/2}+b^{-1/2}=\frac{\sqrt a}a+\frac{\sqrt b}b$$

Answer (score 1):

Rules of fractions + rules of exponents: understand/prove/justify each of the following steps

$$\frac{a^{-1}-b^{-1}}{a^{-1/2}-b^{-1/2}}=\frac{\frac1a-\frac1b}{\frac1{\sqrt a}-\frac1{\sqrt b}}=\frac{\frac{b-a}{ab}}{\frac{\sqrt b-\sqrt a}{\sqrt{ab}}}=\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{ab}\frac{b-a}{\sqrt b-\sqrt a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\left(\sqrt b+\sqrt a\right)=$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt a}+\frac1{\sqrt b}\;\ldots$$

**Added:** Taking from where you understand and taking into account that we know that

$\;(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2\;$ :

$$\frac{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}{a-b}=\frac{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}{(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)}=\frac1{\sqrt a}+\frac1{\sqrt b}$$

Now just check this last expression is **exactly** the same as the one you want...